# C# null coalescing operator with int/long if value of -1

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code assigning variables to 'nullable' int types. As 0 is valid in my use case, -1 signifies a null value in the DB.

This code works just fine on SELECTs as intended

```
int value = (reader["Value"] as int?) ?? -1;
```

However when I am doing the inverse on Update and Inserts. How can I signify a value should be `DBNull.Value` if it's value is -1?

I feel like I am close, but I can't seem to get it to work as intended.

```
insertQuery.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Int).Value = value ?? -1 : (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: [`NULLIF(col, -1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Shouldn't this `value ?? -1 : (object)DBNull.Value;` be `value == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : value`

Comment: @vendettamit That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @vendettamit Yep, that's it. I felt like I was close, thanks! Post your answer below so I can accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your condition from `value ?? -1 : (object)DBNull.Value;` to `value == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : value`

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use a mixture of the null coalescing operator and the conditional `?:` operator. It sounds like you won't get `null` at all as input, so you can't use the null coalescing operator - you just want the conditional operator:

```
(code as before).Value = value == -1 ? (object) DBNull.Value : value;
```

The cast to `object` is required to give the conditional operator a "common" result type.